# How to refresh table cell with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table that shows stock prices but I would like to update the stock price automatically on the page without having the user refresh the page. I have tried this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var updater = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.table #price').load('index.php', 'update=true');
    },6);
});
```

this seems to work but it puts the whole table in the cell. I just want to refresh the price cell. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to JavaScript. I am posting the other files here also.

This is portfolio.php

```
<table class="table table-hover center-table table-bordered">
        <tr>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Shares</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
<?php foreach ($shares as $row): ?>

        <tr>
        <td><?= $row["symbol"]?></td>
        <td><?= $row["name"]?></td>
        <td><?= $row["shares"]?></td>
        <td id="price">$<?= number_format($row["price"],2)?></td>
        <td>$<?= number_format($row["total"],2)?></td>
        </tr>

<? endforeach ?>

<tr>
    <td>CASH</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>$<?= number_format($cash[0]["cash"], 2)?></td>

</tr>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/update.js" ></script>
```

this is index.php

```
<?php

// configuration
require("../includes/config.php"); 

//query user's portfolio

$rows = query("SELECT * FROM shares WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
$cash = query("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);

    //create array to store the shares
    $shares = [];

    //for each of the user info

    foreach($rows as $row){

        //lookup stock info
        $stock = lookup($row["symbol"]);
        if($stock !== false){

            $shares[] = [
                "name" => $stock["name"],
                "price" => $stock["price"],
                "shares" => $row["shares"],
                "symbol" => $row["symbol"],
                "total" => $row["shares"]*$stock["price"]

            ];

        }
    }

// render portfolio
render("portfolio.php", ["shares" => $shares,"cash" => $cash, "title" => "Portfolio"] );   
?>
```

Comment: I must be blind, but where is the element with the ID `price` ?

Comment: a) You cannot have multiple element with id=price
b) You should call a separate php page rendering only the single cell
If you call the same index.php, all the table will be rendered inside the cell

Comment: Oh, now you've added an ID. Does the load function return a complete table from the server, or what is the issue here ?

Comment: It returns the whole table in the "price" cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript will put the whole result of index.php in the cell, which is not what you want.
You have to modify you're php page to only echo the data you want to display in the cell.

Something like that should do the trick (modify it as you need):

```
// ...code to calculate $price...
if (isset($_GET['update'])){
    echo $price;
    exit();
}
```

PS : you could also use another PHP page to return the $price which may be better than calling index.php each time you want to update the price

Comment: I created another file to send the price but I am getting an error
    '$rows = query("SELECT shares FROM shares WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
        $share = [];
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $stock = lookup($row["symbol"]);
            if($stock !== false){
                $share[] = [
                    "price" => $stock["price"] ];}}
    render("portfolio.php", ["share" => $share] );'
this is portfolio.php '<?php foreach ($share as $rows): ?><td id="price">$<?= number_format($rows["price"],2)?></td><? endforeach ?>' The error I am getting:Notice: Undefined variable:share

Comment: Well that's another problem, if your precedent issue as been resolved by one of our answer, please mark it as answered, for your new problem, display more of your code and use something to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

in Jquery you can ask AJAX return the only the value of a certain div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var updater = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.table #price').load('index.php #price', 'update=true');
    },6);
});
```

NOTE: on the above code i assumed that your index.php with the update=true parameter will also have the same index page with the price updated